# Why does the query to find intermediate nodes take so long?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, querying

The database has a graph with the following 3 nodes:

```
...->(1) ------>(3)-->...
   \             ^
    \            |
     ---->(2)---/
```

Now, I want to get all distinct nodes that are reachable from node 1 to node 3, including themselves where I know exactly unique properties of node 1 and node 3 (the nodes are actually commits from a github repository). So, I came up with the following query:

```
MATCH (origin:App)
WHERE origin.commit='10cb31b0a72525923c01dc34f8690f311a361d42'
MATCH (destination:App)
WHERE destination.commit='51fde433973463f057ffcbcbab0bc8944ab3ec9c'
MATCH (origin)-[:CHANGED_TO*0..]->(intermediate_commit:App)-[:CHANGED_TO*0..]->(destination)
RETURN distinct intermediate_commit
```

However, the query never finishes or at least takes too long to complete. I know that I could have used `MATCH p=(origin:App)-[:CHANGED_TO*0..]->(destination:App)` and then UNWIND and return distinct nodes. The problem is, I believe, it queries different paths implying I am interested in relationships between them too. While in fact I am not interested in paths. What I need is only distinct nodes that match the pattern. My understanding is that querying paths is slower than it could be if I could query only the nodes.

Could you please help to understand what I am missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. Instead of specifying a pattern in MATCH clause, we move the pattern to WHERE clause. Also, I split the pattern into 2 parts. I can't explain why exactly it is faster but my understanding is that when we move pattern to WHERE clause and MATCH only nodes, we let neo4j know that we are interested only in nodes and not in all possible paths that match the pattern.

The full query:

```
MATCH (origin:App)
  WHERE origin.commit='10cb31b0a72525923c01dc34f8690f311a361d42'
MATCH (destination:App)
  WHERE destination.commit='51fde433973463f057ffcbcbab0bc8944ab3ec9c'
MATCH (intermediate_commit:App)
  WHERE (origin)-[:CHANGED_TO*0..]->(intermediate_commit)
    AND (intermediate_commit)-[:CHANGED_TO*0..]->(destination)
RETURN distinct intermediate_commit
```

Also, if you have a lot of nodes, I believe specifying LIMIT 1 to match origin and destination can also improve the query, like this:

```
MATCH (origin:App)
  WHERE origin.commit='10cb31b0a72525923c01dc34f8690f311a361d42'
WITH origin
LIMIT 1
MATCH (destination:App)
  WHERE destination.commit='51fde433973463f057ffcbcbab0bc8944ab3ec9c'
WITH origin, destination
LIMIT 1
MATCH (intermediate_commit:App)
  WHERE (origin)-[:CHANGED_TO*0..]->(intermediate_commit)
    AND (intermediate_commit)-[:CHANGED_TO*0..]->(destination)
RETURN distinct intermediate_commit
```

Answer (score 0):

That might be an unbounded path search? Do you really want all paths of any length between the two nodes (e.g. paths spanning the entire graph?)

Does this do what you want?

MATCH (origin:App)
WHERE origin.commit='10cb31b0a72525923c01dc34f8690f311a361d42'
MATCH (destination:App)
WHERE destination.commit='51fde433973463f057ffcbcbab0bc8944ab3ec9c'
MATCH (origin:App)-[:CHANGED_TO *0..1]->(intermediate_commit:App)-[:CHANGED_TO *0..1]->(destination:App)
RETURN distinct intermediate_commit

I bounded the path length to one hop, changing from 0.. to 0..1
(which means minimum 0 hop, up to 1 relationship hop)

Comment: Thank you! The thing is it is not necessarily 0 or 1 hops. I need to find all nodes between any given 2 nodes. Isn't neo4j smart enough to realize that it should not look beyond given origin and destination? Because I clearly specify which origin and destination to use by finding them with WHERE and then bounding the path between them.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern and conditions allow for the possibility of paths that extend past the start or end nodes yet reach them again further down, this is why it doesn't stop when it finds one matching path but keeps expanding beyond it. Remember Cypher is concerned with finding all possible paths that meet the pattern that exist in the graph. And because of your pattern, the check-beyond-the-start-and-end-nodes-without-limit doesn't just happen once, but per potential `(intermediate_commit:App)` found while expanding, this is why your query isn't returning.

One way you can get what you want, all possible paths but stopping when the node is reached, is to use the APOC path expanders, you can supply the node as a terminator node, which will halt further expansion past it.

```
MATCH (origin:App)
WHERE origin.commit='10cb31b0a72525923c01dc34f8690f311a361d42'
MATCH (destination:App)
WHERE destination.commit='51fde433973463f057ffcbcbab0bc8944ab3ec9c'
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(destination, {relationshipFilter:'<CHANGED_TO', terminatorNodes:[origin]}) YIELD path
UNWIND nodes[path] as node
WITH DISTINCT node
WHERE node:App
RETURN node as intermediate_commit
```

This is expanding backwards from destination to origin, seems like that could be more efficient. Once we have the paths, we can UNWIND the nodes from all paths, keep the distinct ones, and make sure we only take the :App nodes.